# receiving old data via php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I've build a small web form with php were I can update & insert some data from a mysql db. The form is prefilled with the data from the db ...So far works all fine... the problem is that when I reload the form I receive the old data from the db... but when I'am looking into the db the updatet/ new data are there... actually I dont use any caching in the web page... don't know what to do ???

...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['createTranslationSet']) && (!empty($id)) ) {

    $connect = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    $mysqli->autocommit(false);

    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `translation-ids`(`ID`) VALUES (NULL)");       
    $mysqli->execute();
    $l10id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("UPDATE places SET places.translationID = ? WHERE places.id = ?");
    $mysqli->bind_param('ii', $l10id, $id); 
    $mysqli->execute();

    $mysqli = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM places WHERE places.id = ?");
    $mysqli->bind_param('i', $id);
    $mysqli->execute();

    $mysqli->fetch();

    echo ($translationID);
```

Comment: "echo ($translationID);" gives always the old data back

Comment: Try Ctrl+F5 to refresh to make sure that there's no caching involved.

Comment: Where is the value for `$translationID` set? Also I see you are using `$_REQUEST`.  Is your form data passed via POST or GET?

Comment: @Javid ... I've cleared the cache everytime

Comment: @MikeBrant the code is only a part of the form... if there is no "TranslationSet" you can create one with this piece of code... this will echo out the translationID

Comment: @MikBrant .. the form works well... the new data will be passed to the db

Comment: Modify the "echo" to `echo $translationID, ' ', microtime(TRUE);` and see if the time is updated.

Comment: @Bob Yes but you mention that the problem is that `$translationID` is always the old value, yet you have shown no code around how it is set.  You do a `$mysqli->fetch()` without setting the value to anything either so from you code sample it is not clear how the value you are interested in is actually supposed to get populated with the "new" data, or how it is populated with the "old" data for that matter.

Comment: I think there is a problem how i svae the data... when I set the value with phpMyAdmin or NaviCat the results looks ok

Comment: @J.D.Pace i've tried it... the time is updated... but the value null

Comment: How/where is `$translationID` set?